# Responsive JustGage JAUGE

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, justgage

Does anyone know how to make JustGage object responsive ? 
Please Check the link below, I fix the issue with raphael but can't get do the same  with JustGage:

```
window.onload = function () {
  var g1 = new JustGage({
    id: "g1",
    value: getRandomInt(0, 4000),
    min: 0,
    max: 4000,
    title: "Well over thousand",
    label: ""
  });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ugFmE/

Answer (score 5):

Simply add `relativeGaugeSize: true` in to your code

No need fixed height

```
#g1 {
    /* width: 400px; */
    /* height:300px; */
}
```

script

```
var g1 = new JustGage({
  id: "g1", 
  value: getRandomInt(0, 4000), 
  min: 0,
  max: 4000,
  title: "Well over thousand",
  label: "",
  relativeGaugeSize: true
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ugFmE/10/

Comment: As of May 2015, a "work-in-progress, unreleased, unofficial code" must be used for relativeGaugeSize feature as written in header of http://justgage.com/justgage.js. See demo at http://justgage.com/demos/responsive-gauges/.